# Improve method - better way to write this method?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, refactoring

Is there a better way to write this method in C#? I really want to refactor this method in order to make it more efficient, but don't know how to. This string is the body of a `SELECT DISTINCT someID + selectList FROM tableName WHERE conditions` query.

```
private static string CreateQueryBody(IList<string> someList){
{
    var selectList = string.Empty;
    foreach(string colName in someList)
    {
        if(selList.Length > 0)
        {
            selList = "{fn CONCAT(" + selList + ",' - ')}";
            selList = "{fn CONCAT(" + selList + "," + colName + ")}";
        }
        else
        {
            selList = colName;
        }
    }
    return selList;
}
```

The outcome of the return is:

```
{fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT
({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT
({fn CONCAT(someId,' - ')},some_name)},' - ')},some_lastName)},' - ')},someVariable)},' - ')},someCompany)},' - ')},postalAcc)},' - ')},someDescription)}
```

I would be great if this method could be written without hard coded strings.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this should be on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The expected outcome is the modification of a DataList Service, meaning that the list will a different description depending on the contents of the list: example of the full sql query: SELECT DISTINCT someId, {fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT(some_name,' - ')},some_LastName)},' - ')},postal_acc)} FROM someTable WHERE myVar=@myVar AND status IN ('N') ORDER BY 1

Comment: Requirement is unclear. What is this method expected to do? Why this way?

Comment: The method returns  the columns which are supposed to be used in a sql select distinct query depending on the contents of the list